# Send multiples DTOs using Kafka Template

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

What's the better approach to send multiple types of DTOs using Kafka Template?

Approach 1: Use **Object** as a type value for the ProducerFactory so I can send many types of Objects using my Kafka Template.

```
@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, Object> ProducerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(config);
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, Object> KafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(ProducerFactory());
}
```

Approach 2: Add another ProducerFactory and Kafka Template configuration for each Object I want to send.

```
@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, Student> ProducerFactory1() {
    Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(config);
}

public ProducerFactory<String, Person> ProducerFactory2() {
    Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(config);
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, Student> leadTimeKafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(ProducerFactory());
}
 @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, Person> leadTimeKafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(ProducerFactory());
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `KafkaTemplate<String, Object> KafkaTemplate()` is fine when using a serializer such as JSON.

In fact, the generic type on the template is only important when using one of the `receive()` methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use JSONSerializer, use JsonNode from Jackson, not plain Java Object which may not serialize properly, and wouldn't prevent bad inputs into the topic (e.g. you have lots of domain models, not all of which are meant to be used in Kafka, and you accidentally send one instead of another).

Otherwise, either will work, but the Kafka Javadoc recommends that you only use one Producer instance, if possible

Comment: thank you for your comment, so you suggest that I use JsonNode instead of Object to serialize my DTOs instead of using multiples Kafka Templates? Is that what you would do? Thanks!

Comment: I primarily use Avro, and you can use GenericRecord type there, but same concept, yes.

Comment: Using `Object` in the generic type for the template is fine for JSON and Avro - the generic type is really only important on the template when using one of the `receive()` methods.